# gnuradio phase drift of AM demodulation

Tags: audio, signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am beginning a project using GNUradio and an inexpensive SDR.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00SXZDUAQ?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_search_detailpage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SXZDUAQ)

One portion of the project requires me to generate a reference audio tone and compare the phase of that tone to demodulated audio.

To simulate this portion of the system, I have generated a simple GNUradio flowchart:

[image: gnuradio flowgraph]

I had some issues with the source and demodulated audio in that they would drift relative to each other.  This occurred on the scope sync on the original flowgraph.  To aid in troubleshooting I sent the demodulated audio out thru the soundcard’s second channel and monitored both audio streams in addition to the modulated RF on an external oscilloscope:

[image: scope photo #1]

Initially all seems well but, the demodulated audio drifts in relation to the original source and RF:

[image: scope photo #2]

My question is: am I doing something wrong in the flowgraph or am I expecting too much performance out of an inexpensive SDR?

Thanks in advance for any insights

Comment: Just FYI, in general you shouldn't expect people to download a file from an external site to get parts of your question. You now have enough reputation to embed as many links or images as you like; I recommend that you edit your question to have the images embedded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the question as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot expect to see zero phase drift in anything short of a fully digital simulation, or a fully analog circuit with exactly one oscillator, because no two (physical) oscillators have identical frequencies.

In your case, there are two relevant oscillators involved:

1. The sample clock in the RTL-SDR unit.
2. The sample clock in your sound card output.

Within an GNU Radio flowgraph, there is no time reference per se and everything depends on the sources and sinks which are connected to hardware.

The relevant source in your flowgraph is the RTL-SDR hardware; insofar as its oscillator is different from its nominal value (28.8 MHz, as it happens), everything it produces will be off-frequency in an absolute sense (both RF carrier frequencies *and* audio frequencies of demodulated output).

But you don't actually have an absolute frequency reference; you have the tone produced by your sound card. The sound card has its own oscillator, which determines the rate at which samples are converted to analog signals, and therefore the rate at which samples are consumed from the flowgraph.

Therefore, your reference signal will drift relative to your received and demodulated signal, at a rate determined by the difference in frequency error between the two oscillators.

Additionally, since your sound card will be *accepting* samples from the flowgraph at a slightly different real-time rate than the RTL-SDR is *producing* them, you will notice periodic glitches in the audio as the error accumulates and must be dealt with; they will start occurring either immediately (if the source is slower than the sink, requiring the sound card to play silence instead) or after a delay for buffers to hit their maximum size (if the source is faster than the sink, requiring the RTL-SDR to drop some samples).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  One small clarification: the modulation source isn't the audio oscillator in the RF signal generator (transmitter),  the modulation is being generated within the  GNU flowgraph and being sent out thru the sound card to the sig gen.  That being said, there is still a difference between the RTL-SDR and the computer's sound card.  Since everything is being controlled by GNU radio, is there any way to sync things so that the relative, not necessarily zero, phase between the source signal and the demodulated result can be determined?

Comment: @EdColeman I've updated my answer to correct that part. Yes, you can get synchronization, by using a common clock reference (traditionally 10 MHz), but this is a high-end feature not present on either RTL-SDR or consumer sound cards. You could do it with a Ettus USRP, for example.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: and even with a USRP, you'd have to use a device that explicitly supports constant phase after tuning, and a clock distributor to get both the PPS as well as the 10MHz to all USRPs involved, and you'd have to program them to do the tuning at the same instant.